# Python How to Get All Rectangular Subsets of a 2D list

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, subset, rectangles

Say I'm given a 2D list

```
001
111
111
```

And I want to get all possible subsets of the 2D list that are rectangular and contain the upper left corner element/the element at `grid[0][0]` (I don't know how else to describe it)

It should output:

```
0

00

001

0
1

00
11

001
111

0
1
1

00
11
11

001
111
111
```

How would you get all possible subsets? I don't have the vaguest idea on how to implement it.

Comment: Do you want to do this for each row in your 2D list?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate? I want to get all rectangular subset of the entire array that contains the top-left item in the array

Comment: Okay..for example, is '011' also an option  for you?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov Yes, if you mean the 1st column of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        x = grid[0:i+1]
        for k in x:
            print(k[0:j+1])
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanations, I came up with the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

list1=[[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]

df=pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['a','b','c'])

list2=[]



for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        list2.append(df.iloc[:i,:j].to_numpy('int').tolist())
```

Output:

```
[[[0]], 
 [[0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 1]],
 [[0], [1]],
 [[0, 0], [1, 1]],
 [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
 [[0], [1], [1]],
 [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]],
 [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]
```

If you wish to have higher order matrices, then you just need to change the 4 into the number that you wish in `for i/j in range(2,4)`.

Comment: All the combinations do contain the element at [0][0], please have a careful look at the output. It is a 2D list....have a look at the elements within the 2 square brackets...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the program and dataframe. This is a nice solution, but is there a way to do it without `numpy`?

Comment: Thanks! I adapted a solution that doesn't have to use `numpy`, although the time complexity for my implementation isn't that good.

Comment: That's nice to hear! Happy that my answer was useful

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

ints = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
]

def get_slice(ints, x, y):
    rows = ints[0:y+1]
    return list(map(lambda row: row[0:x+1], rows))

x_max = len(ints[0]) # Assuming all rows have the same length
y_max = len(ints)

for coord in product(range(x_max), range(y_max)):
    for row in get_slice(ints, *coord):
        print(*row)
    print()
```

Output:

```
0

0
1

0
1
1

0 0

0 0
1 1

0 0
1 1
1 1

0 0 1

0 0 1
1 1 1

0 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

---

`get_slice` first slices `ints` based on the parameter `y`, which yields only the  'rows' that we're interested in. We then slice each row according to the parameter `x`.

We use `itertools.product` to generate all possible xy-coordinates, and use those as arguments for `get_slice`.